# Using link-to with or without an #

Tags: ember.js

The Ember guide contains the following example code at http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/links/

```
A link in {{#link-to 'index'}}Block Expression Form{{/link-to}},
and a link in {{link-to 'Inline Form' 'index'}}.
```

It uses `link-to` with and without an `#`. Why? Which one is correct?

Comment: You should read the rest of the documentation, the answer to your question is right [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/links/#toc_using-link-to-as-an-inline-helper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them. `{{#link-to 'index'}}Block Expression Form{{/link-to}}` allows you to express the link in a block way, like any other html element, for example `<p></p>`. You can write any string in the middle or even another html element/ember component.

`{{link-to 'Inline Form' 'index'}}` is an inline mode. The link will look as `<a href='/'>Inline Form</a>`.

The difference is that in the inline mode you can only type strings like `Inline Form` and in the block way you can have whatever you want.